# spring cloud ribbon connect to server which doesn't have the service

Tags: spring, cloud, spring-cloud-consul

I have two restful service server(node1 and node2) with same application name, both of the producer have restful service A.

Then I added a new restful service B, after I deploy the new service to node1.
Now, when consumer request service B, sometimes it will route to node2, will got one 404 exception.

Why the consul cannot know which server have service B, and only route to the server with service B?

Comment: What configuration you have added at API Gateway?

Comment: Not using api gateway, just use feign as client.

Comment: check with this https://dzone.com/articles/spring-cloud-netflix-load-balancer-with-ribbonfeig